# Using the ternary operator in a macro

Tags: c, macros, ternary-operator

I'm trying to combine 2 macro templates into a third one to basically check if the entered character is an alphabet. I'm trying to use the ternary operator into the first two macros and then using the #if directive to reach conclusion but some syntax error continuously shows up. Anybody can help me out maybe?

```
#define SMALLCASE(X) (X>96&&X<123)?1:2); 
#define UPPERCASE(X) (X>64&&X<91)?1:2);
#define TEST(X) (SMALLCASE(X))&&(UPPERCASE(X))

/*in main() after reading character*/
#if TEST(ch)
printf("Entered character is an alphabet");
#else
printf("Entered character isn't an alphabet");
#endif
printf("%d",SMALLCASE(ch));
```

Comment: Note that your parenthesis are unbalanced.

Comment: You can't use `#if` here. Use regular `if`. Better yet, throw away all this stuff and use `if(isalpha(ch))`.

Comment: `gcc -E` will output the code after the preprocessor took action, try it.. it'll help you.

Comment: Your code would be a bit less cryptic if you used char literals instead of magic numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`?

Comment: Your macro has 1 `(` and 2 `)`

Comment: why use `>64` and `<91` when what you want is `>'a'` and `<'z'`? 64 and 91 aren't necessarily a to z in other chararacter sets

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Note that `'A'` is often 65 (not 64), and `'Z'` is often 90; similarly, `'a'` is often 97 and `'z'` is often 122.  It goes to demonstrate why the numbers are a bad idea!  You also need to take care to branch the correct way on equality (`>= 'a'` and `<= 'z'`, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have got several errors here.

- You cannot use `#if` since the preprocessor does not know the character you will enter.
- Use `||` in the macro `TEST` instead of `&&`
- Parenthesis errors in `SMALLCASE` and `UPPERCASE` macros (only one `(` but two `)`)
- Remove semicolons in the `SMALLCASE` and `UPPERCASE` macros
- Prefer using char value (like `'a'`) instead of its ASCII value (for instance 97)

What you could do then:

```
#define SMALLCASE(X) (((X)>='a') && ((X)<='z'))
#define UPPERCASE(X) (((X)>='A') && ((X)<='Z'))
#define TEST(X) ((SMALLCASE(X)) || (UPPERCASE(X)))

/*in main() after reading character*/
if (TEST(ch)) {
    printf("Entered character is an alphabet\n");
} else {
    printf("Entered character isn't an alphabet\n");
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @GineetMehta welcome to Stack Overflow! If you found this answer as helpful, please select the checkmark next to it, indicating that it was correct and most helpful to you.

Comment: You need to enclose the `X`'s in the expansion in their own individual parentheses so that things don't go wrong if an expression is passed to the macro.  It could be a problem with these macros if someone uses `SMALLCASE(ch & 0x7F)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to remove the semicolons. Apart from this your macro `TEST`is always true. Adapt your code like this:

```
#define SMALLCASE(X) ( (X) >= 'a' && (X) <= 'z' ) 
                                              // ^ removed ;
#define UPPERCASE(X) ( (X) >= 'A' && (X) <= 'Z' )
                                              // ^ removed ; 
#define TEST(X) ( SMALLCASE(X) || UPPERCASE(X) )
```

Here the solution with ternary operators:

```
#define SMALLCASE(X) ( ( (X) >= 'a' && (X) <= 'z' ) ? 1 : 2 )
#define UPPERCASE(X) ( ( (X) >= 'A' && (X) <= 'Z' ) ? 1 : 2 )
#define TEST(X) ( SMALLCASE(X) == 1 || UPPERCASE(X) == 1 )
```

Further you can't use a variable in a preprocessor statement; either you use a other preprocessor statement and define `ch`:

```
#define ch 'a'

#if TEST(ch)
    printf("Entered character is an alphabet");
#else
    printf("Entered character isn't an alphabet");
#endif
```

or you use an if statement:

```
if ( TEST(ch) )
{
    printf("Entered character is an alphabet");
}
else
{
    printf("Entered character isn't an alphabet");
}
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work. No compile-time errors but not giving the desired output.

Comment: @GineetMehta see @jyvet's answer, the reason why is because you're using preprocessor `#if` instead of runtime `if`. User input can't be processed at compile-time, only run-time.

Comment: ya because you cannot use `#if` but instead `if` no hash tag `#`

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks @PatrickRoberts, that really helped!

Comment: Technically, you can use `#if TEST(ch)` but it is looking for a macro named `ch` and if it is not defined, the value 0 will be substituted.  It's still definitely not what is wanted, but it does actually compile — albeit to something unexpected.